# Speeding up docker build for golang vendoring

Tags: go, docker

I have a Dockerfile which is `FROM golang:1.6-alpine`. I’d like to use the docker images cache as much as possible while performing `docker build` to speed things up.

For this, I thought I’d add `ADD vendor /go/src/…/mypackage/vendor` as one of the first steps, and eventually run `go install -v …/mypackage`. However, this causes the vendored packages (which are the bulk of the build time) to only be built then.

Is there anyway to explicitly build all vendored packages (i.e. sources inside a `…/vendor` dir), but only them?

I'd like my Dockerfile to look something like this:

```
FROM golang:1.6-alpine

ADD vendor /go/src/github.com/myuser/package/vendor
# missing: magic command to build only the vendored packages above

ADD *.go /go/src/github.com/myuser/package
RUN go install -v "github.com/myuser/package
```

Comment: You could install everything and remove the build artifacts for your package.

Comment: AFAIK `go install` compiles all packages and stores them to `$GOPATH/pkg`. So you could run `go install` in a clean `$GOPATH` and copy these files. Unfortunately I don't have time to verify this, now.

Comment: You can also make your own base image from the vendor packages and extend the user images FROM that. As mentioned, you can do any cleanup, etc. in your base image. This would make it possible to do a clean build if need be later and still be able to reuse the vendor (base) image.

Answer (score 2):

- In the host (outside the docker container), the packages are still stored in the `/vendor` folder. This allows for convenient management of these dependencies. Personally I use `godep` to manage this.
- Inside the container, instead of adding the `/vendor` folder to be a subdir of my package, I add all the packages inside the `/vendor` folder under the source directory `/go/src` directly.
- Since go's vendoring is all about changing import paths, and build artifacts are stored in the `/pkg` directory regardless of whether they were 'vendored' or not, this solution is stable.
- In order to enjoy the speed-up, and not having to rebuild all vendored packages unless they were changed, the Dockerfile runs a `go install ./...` on the `src` dir after adding the `vendor` folder, then proceeds with the rest of the build.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.6-alpine

# Add and install all vendored packages.
ADD vendor /go/src/
RUN cd /go/src && go install -v ./...

# ...

# Add and install our package's source files, without the vendor folder
ADD *.go "/go/src/github.com/myuser/mypackage"
RUN go install -v "/go/src/github.com/myuser/mypackage"
```